# mathabx integrals look different from documentation

Tags: packages, typography

According to the "Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List" (http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/files/symbols-all.pdf) mathabx integrals look like

[image]

But when I run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$\int\quad\displaystyle\int$
\end{document}
```

it produces the following:

[image]

How do I get the symbols shown in the first picture?

If it helps, I am running TeXmaker 5.0.2 on Mac OS.

Comment: The version of the "Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List" you've come across on some website is rather outdated -- September 2005 -- and lists 3300 symbols. The current version of the Comprehensive List -- open a command window and type `texdoc comprehensive` -- is dated January 2017 and lists 14,283 [!!] symbols. In Table 76, on p. 40 of the more recent document, you'll find that the `\int` symbols are those that are produced by your own MWE. Moral of the story: Do work with up-to-date versions of all documents. (Aside: I have *no knowledge* of when or why the `mathabx` symbol shapes changed.)

Comment: I could go back and test with TeX Live 2008, getting exactly the same result as your second image. According to the TeX Live repository, the sources for the `mathx` font hasn't changed for 11 years, that is, since `mathabx` is in TeX Live.